# Strange memory problem of Loki::Singleton, Loki::SmartPtr, and std::vector

Tags: c++, c++-loki

I had encountered a problem while using **Loki::Singleton**, **Loki::SmartPtr**, and **std::vector**  under VC express 2008. Following is my source.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <loki/Singleton.h>
#include <loki/SmartPtr.h>

class Foo {
  public:
    std::vector<Loki::SmartPtr<Foo>> children ;
    void add() {
        Loki::SmartPtr<Foo> f = new Foo ;
        children.push_back(f) ;
    }
    Foo () {
    }
    ~Foo () {
    }
} ;

typedef Loki::SingletonHolder<Foo> SingletonFoo ;

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl ;
    SingletonFoo::Instance().add() ;
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl ;
}
```

Compiling and linking has no problem, but after the program finished, an error pops:

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in test.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in test.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while test.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

It *seems* some memory are deleted twice, I am quite not sure. Is that a bug of VC or I miss used Loki?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using VC, you should be able to run your code in debug mode, step by stp (F10,F11) to see where it breaks.

Anyway, looking at the [Loki singleton code](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00670.html), it seems that the error comes from the assert in SingletonHolder::DestroySingleton() :

```
 SingletonHolder<T, CreationPolicy, L, M, X>::DestroySingleton()
00837     {
00838         assert(!destroyed_); // there, but it's a wild guess
00839         CreationPolicy<T>::Destroy(pInstance_);
00840         pInstance_ = 0;
00841         destroyed_ = true;
00842     }
```

That function seems to be called by the LifetimePolicy (here DefaultLifetime) as this code suggests :

```
00800     template
00801     <
00802         class T,
00803         template <class> class CreationPolicy,
00804         template <class> class LifetimePolicy,
00805         template <class, class> class ThreadingModel,
00806         class MutexPolicy
00807     >
00808     void SingletonHolder<T, CreationPolicy, 
00809         LifetimePolicy, ThreadingModel, MutexPolicy>::MakeInstance()
00810     {
00811         typename ThreadingModel<SingletonHolder,MutexPolicy>::Lock guard;
00812         (void)guard;
00813         
00814         if (!pInstance_)
00815         {
00816             if (destroyed_)
00817             {
00818                 destroyed_ = false;
00819                 LifetimePolicy<T>::OnDeadReference();
00820             }
00821             pInstance_ = CreationPolicy<T>::Create();
00822             LifetimePolicy<T>::ScheduleDestruction(pInstance_, // here
00823                 &DestroySingleton);
00824         }
00825     }
```

I'm not sure why it is called twice, but I guess the pointer to the singleton is first destroyed (the pointer, not the instance) on the SingletonHolder instance destruction and then the LifetimePolicy try to call it's DestroySingleton() function...

But I might be wrong, you'll have to check that.

Answer (score 1):

IMR, you can't use certain smart pointers in stl containers, and this is the exact problem that occurs.  If memory serves, it has to do with how the stl containers copy the values not conforming to how smart pointers expect to be used.

Comment: I rechecked the usage of Loki::SmartPtr, the default policy is reference count, which has the same behavior with Boost::shared_ptr, support a value semantic, and can be used in STL container. Is there any other possible explaination? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you suspect your objects are getting deleted twice, have you tried sticking breakpoints in your destructor and checking the call stack?

Answer (score 0):

Loki's smart pointers have no problems with STL containers. If you re-write this sample this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <loki/Singleton.h>
#include <loki/SmartPtr.h>

class Foo {
  public:
    std::vector<Loki::SmartPtr<Foo>> children ;
    void add() {
        Loki::SmartPtr<Foo> f = new Foo ;
        children.push_back(f) ;
    }
    Foo () {
    }
    ~Foo () {
    }
} ;

// typedef Loki::SingletonHolder<Foo> SingletonFoo ;

int main ()
{
    Loki::SmartPtr<Foo> root = new Foo;
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl ;
    // SingletonFoo::Instance().add() ;
    root->add();
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl ;
}
```

it works without any problems.

What is happening here, is that same class isn't supposed be used as `Loki::Singleton` and in `Loki::SmartPtr` at the same time - it's created and destroyed directly in `Loki::Singleton`, but reference count is maintained for `Loki::SmartPtr`.

But if you use `Loki::SmartPtr<Foo>` as parameter of `Loki::Singleton` it works! The only modification you have to make to your code is a specialization of `Loki::CreateUsingNew` class to create `Loki::SmartPtr<Foo>` initialized with freshly created `Foo`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <loki/Singleton.h>
#include <loki/SmartPtr.h>

class Foo {
  public:
    std::vector<Loki::SmartPtr<Foo>> children ;
    void add() {
        Loki::SmartPtr<Foo> f = new Foo ;
        children.push_back(f) ;
    }
    Foo () {
    }
    ~Foo () {
    }
};

namespace Loki {
    template<class T>
    struct CreateUsingNew<class Loki::SmartPtr<T>> {
        static Loki::SmartPtr<T>* Create()
        { return new Loki::SmartPtr<T>(new T); }

        static void Destroy(Loki::SmartPtr<T>* p)
        { delete p; }
    };
}

typedef Loki::SingletonHolder<Loki::SmartPtr<Foo>> SingletonFoo ;

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl ;
    SingletonFoo::Instance()->add() ;
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl ;
}
```